# Why does my code only execute once

Tags: java

I want to print all the even numbers, but it only gives me 0!!

```
public class DataType {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int number=0;
    int max=20;
    do{
        System.out.println("this is an even number"+ number);
        number++;
    }while(number<=max&&EvenNumber(number));

}



public static boolean EvenNumber(int a)
{
    if((a%2)==0)
    {
        return true;
    }else 
        return false;       
}


}
```

Comment: Because `number` will be 1 after the first execution so your `EvenNumber` check will return false. Attach a debugger next time.

Comment: @Kon you mean *1, right

Comment: In integer arithmetic, even numbers are never consecutive; they are always inter-spaced with odd numbers.  If you add `1` to any even number, you'll get an odd number, at which point your break out of your loop.

Answer (score 2):

that is what  your condition states: do while both conditions meet!, afters doing number++ for the 1st time the left side of the condition returns false and your loop is done!

you mean for sure:

```
    do {
        if (isEvenNumber(number)) {
            System.out.println("this is an even number" + number);
        }
        number++;
    } while (number <= max);
```

remember, following code means

```
while(number <= max && EvenNumber(number))
```

while **BOTH** conditions meet...

Comment: So once my condition statement in the do while loop is false, it makes the entire loop stop?

Answer (score 0):

After `number++;`, `number` becomes `1`, and thus the condition becomes `false`, and the loop terminates.

I assume, you wanted to do

```
do {
    if (isEvenNumber(number)) System.out.println(number);
    number++;
} while(number<=max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in your code, If number is equals to 1, while condition is false

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to find all even number between `[0, 20]` you may change your code to this version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int max=20;
    for (int number = 0; number <= max; number++) {
        if (number % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.printf("%d is an even number.\n", number);
        }
    }
}
```

This reads like:

- start with number 0
- while number not past 20
- if number is even print it
- continue with next number

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second iteration the loop will exit.
if you want to print even numbers then the code should be

```
do{
    if(EvenNumber(number)) {
        System.out.println("this is an even number"+ number);
    }
    number++;
}while(number<=max );
```